# db2 V9.1 deadlocks

Tags: sql, db2, odbc, deadlock

I have 4 different services in my application which `SELECT` and `UPDATE` on the same table in my database (db2 v9.1) on AIX 6.1, not big table around 300,000 records.The 4 services work execute in parallel way, and each service execute in sequential way (not parallel).
The issue that everyday I face horrible deadlock problem, the db hangs for about 5 to 10 minutes then it get back to its normal performance.
My services are synchronized in a way which make them never `SELECT` or `UPDATE` on the same row so I believe even if a deadlock occurred it supposed to be on a row level not table level, RIGHT? 
Also, in my `SELECT` queries I use `"ONLY FOR FETCH WITH UR"`, in db2 v9.1 that means not to lock the row as its only for read purpose and there will be no update (`UR` = uncommitted read).
Any Ideas about whats happening and why?

Comment: `WITH UR` does *not* mean that your `SELECT` statement won't hold locks! `WITH UR` means that you are willing to read through other transactions' locks.

Comment: @IanBjorhovde -- actually, the UR isolation level _does_ mean that the SELECT takes no locks, on data anyway.

Comment: Ok, so why does lock wait take that much time?? is that normal behavior, taking inconsideration that all the queries in my application never read or update the same row at the same time?

Comment: Here is the thing: I noticed that when the issue occurs it is almost at the same time. For example 01:02 till 01:07, 03:03 till 03:08 and so on. Wired but true. Also, we checked if there is any scheduled jobs on that server or any monitoring jobs but actually we found nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, these are certainly not deadlocks: a deadlock would be resolved by DB2 within few seconds by rolling back one of the conflicting transactions. What you are experiencing are most likely lock waits.

As to what's happening, you will need to monitor locks as they occur. You can use the `db2pd` utility, e.g.

```
db2pd -d mydb -locks showlocks
```

or

```
db2pd -d mydb -locks wait
```

You can also use the snapshot monitor:

```
db2 update monitor switches using statement on lock on
db2 get snapshot for locks on mydb
```

or the snapshot views:

```
select * from sysibmadm.locks_held
select * from sysibmadm.lockwaits
```

Comment: Ok, so why does lock wait take that much time?? is that normal behavior, taking inconsideration that all the queries in my application never read or update the same row at the same time?

Comment: Here is the thing: I noticed that when the issue occurs it is almost at the same time. For example 01:02 till 01:07, 03:03 till 03:08 and so on. Wired but true. Also, we checked if there is any scheduled jobs on that server or any monitoring jobs but actually we found nothing.

Comment: The methods I suggested should answer all your questions.

Comment: Thanks, one more questions: will it work if I changed the LOCKTIMEOUT attribute on db level?

Comment: Changing the LOCKTIMEOUT to something less, lets say to 60 seconds. It will make locks expire? Right?

Comment: No, it will not "make locks expire". The applications waiting for locks for more than 60 seconds will get errors. I suggest you start reading documentation.

Comment: Thanks. We figured it out. It was logs archiving issue. Db2 was unable to archive its logs correctly and thats why it was hanging.